# In React Google Maps, getting "'google' is not defined" even when component is wrapped with withScriptjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm trying to reproduce the example in https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#groundoverlay in a React project created with `create-react-app`; what I have so far is at https://github.com/khpeek/trailmaps.

In `src/components`, I have a `groundOverlay.js` as follows:

```
import React from 'react';

const { compose } = require("recompose");
const {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  GroundOverlay,
} = require("react-google-maps");

const MapWithGroundOverlay = compose(
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props =>
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={12}
    defaultCenter={{lat: 40.740, lng: -74.18}}
  >
    <GroundOverlay
      defaultUrl="https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg"
      defaultBounds={new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(40.712216, -74.22655),
        new google.maps.LatLng(40.773941, -74.12544)
      )}
      defaultOpacity={.5}
    />
  </GoogleMap>
);
```

Then, in `App.js`, I have

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import MapWithAnOverlayView from './components/overlayView';
import MapWithGroundOverlay from './components/groundOverlay';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Custom Overlay</h1>
        </header>
        <MapWithGroundOverlay
          googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBimnrhiugaGSNN8WnsjpzMNJcrH_T60GI&v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
          loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Any idea why this is not working? Is this not the right way to do it?

Comment: can you share codesandbox for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define for eslint that `google` is the global variable like

```
/* global google */
```

You can put this at the top of the file where you use

```
defaultBounds={new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.712216, -74.22655),
    new google.maps.LatLng(40.773941, -74.12544)
)}
```

To make your code work, you need to also export correctly component from the `groundOverlay.js` file, like this:

```
/* global google */
import React from 'react';

const { compose } = require("recompose");
const {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  GroundOverlay,
} = require("react-google-maps");

const MapWithGroundOverlay = compose(
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap
)(props =>
  <GoogleMap
    defaultZoom={12}
    defaultCenter={{lat: 40.740, lng: -74.18}}
  >
    <GroundOverlay
      defaultUrl="https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg"
      defaultBounds={new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(40.712216, -74.22655),
        new google.maps.LatLng(40.773941, -74.12544)
      )}
      defaultOpacity={.5}
    />
  </GoogleMap>
);

export default MapWithGroundOverlay;
```

When you do this, it should work, screen below.

[image]

I will create a PR to your repo, so you will can merge it and continue working.

Pull request created: https://github.com/khpeek/trailmaps/pull/1

Comment: Great! I wasn't aware that ESLint was 'active', but it would appear to be bundled with `create-react-app` (cf. https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-react-app). For reference, here is the documentation on specifying globals: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals

Answer (score 0):

Sing google is a global variable, you need to read it explicitly using `window` this way

```
const google = window.google;
```

or you can directly access it

```
new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds()
```

The ESlint fix can be done this way by declaring it at the top of your file

```
/*global google*/
```

Answer (score -4):

try to use `declare var google;` before **@Component**

Example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import MapWithAnOverlayView from './components/overlayView';
import MapWithGroundOverlay from './components/groundOverlay';

declare var google;

class App extends Component {

}
```