# react-google-maps - Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in ReactJS, currently I'm using react-google-maps for a project, I'm showing some places using FourSquare API, there is a Direction button which is supposed to show the direction from users' current location to the destination.

Here's Meeting.js

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */
/* global google */
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Map from '../../Component/Map';
import MapAPI from '../../api/GoogleMap';

class Meeting extends Component {
// constructor and other stuff...

getDirections = () => {
const DirectionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

DirectionsService.route(
  {
    destination: new google.maps.LatLng(24.8861479, 67.0595196),
    origin: new google.maps.LatLng(24.8812296, 67.0727269),
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
  },
  (result, status) => {
    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      this.setState({
        directions: result,
        mapLoaded: true,
        mapVisible: true,
      });
    } else {
      alert("Sorry! Can't calculate directions!");
    }
  },
);
};

render() {
const { coords, directions, mapVisible } = this.state;

return (
  <div className="section">
    {mapVisible && (
      <Map
        coords={coords}
        dragged={this.dragged}
        isMarkerShown
        directions={directions}
        googleMapURL={MapAPI}
        loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        containerElement={<div style={{ height: `350px` }} />}
        mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
      />
    )}
  </div>
);
}
}

export default Meeting;
```

Here is Map.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  DirectionsRenderer,
} from 'react-google-maps';

const Map = withScriptjs(
  withGoogleMap(props => (
    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={14}
      defaultCenter={{
        lat: props.coords.latitude,
        lng: props.coords.longitude,
      }}
      center={{ lat: props.coords.latitude, lng: props.coords.longitude }}
    >
      {props.isMarkerShown && (
        <Marker
          draggable={props.draggable || false}
          onDragEnd={e => props.dragged(e)}
          position={{ lat: props.coords.latitude, lng: props.coords.longitude }}
        />
      )}

      {props.directions && <DirectionsRenderer directions={props.directions} />}
    </GoogleMap>
  )),
);

export default Map;
```

The `getDirections` function is called on a button, it's neither working on componentDidMount neither on button click, in both cases I'm getting same error.

I think it's because of the async loading of Google from but couldn't find a way to fix this, I saw same question's being asked but not satisfactory answer is there.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can access `new google.maps...` outside of the component where you import 'react-google-maps'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67870982/7473966

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>This is because you import `react-google-maps` in your `Map.js` and you are calling `google` in your `Meeting.js`, google is available in your `Map.js` - try using it in there and you will be ready to go!</strike>

https://codesandbox.io/embed/nkykvozl34

UPDATE:

The configuration of the package `react-google-maps` has been updated:
https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#usage--configuration